# Pytest: How to call the patch of a fixture

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest, patch, fixtures

pytest 5.0.1
python 3.6

Imagine that you have a class that you import and initialize in another class

```
from file import Client
class A()

    def __init__(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def call(self):
        self.client.execute()
```

Now when I want to test it, because this import class touches outside components (e.g. a database), I want to mock the thing from happening (e.g. I can't believe you read databases so slowly...). But for reals. So I have a fixture with a patch in it. Yay!

```
 @pytest.fixture
 def setup_a(self):
    with patch('path_to_patch') as patched:
        a = A()
    return a
```

However, I can't seem to get the patch out of the fxiture to use it. I've tried creating a new patch, but this doesn't work (e.g. assert False)

```
@patch('path_to_patch')
def test_successful_execution(self, new_patch, setup_a):
    setup_a.call()
    assert new_patch.execute.called
```

I've also tried using the above patch implicitly

```
@patch('path_to_patch')
def test_successful_execution(self, new_patch, setup_a):
    setup_a.call()
    assert setup_a.execute.called
```

What is the right way to do this? Let me know if you need more of an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to patch `Client.execute` in `A`, and the fixture shall return an object of type `A` with that patch in place. The first thing is to make sure that the patching is still active:

```py
 @pytest.fixture
 def mocked_a(self):
     with patch('path_to_a.Client.execute'):
         yield A()
```

In your example you had the object returned after the patching scope, meaning the patching had already ended at that point. Also note that you have to patch the `Client` module as imported in the `a` module (assuming that is where `A` is defined).

To use the patched object, you can now:

```py
def test_successful_execution(mocked_a):
    mocked_a.call()
    mocked_a.Client.execute.assert_called_once()
```

Note that you can access the mock the same way you mocked it.

Alternatively, you can return the mock itself in the fixture:

```py
 @pytest.fixture
 def mocked_execute(self):
     with patch('path_to_a.Client.execute') as patched:
         yield patched

def test_successful_execution(mocked_execute):
    a = A()
    a.call()
    mocked_execute.assert_called_once()
```

This way you explicitely create the object in your test, and the test is more clear, in my opinion.

(this is out of my head, so there may be errors...)